# Ocultar contenido en vistas dependiendo del Permiso y Rol de Usuario ASP NET MVC 5

Tags: c#

Tengo este codigo en el cual trato de ocultar algunos modulos dependiendo del rol, el rol y el usuario los almaceno en un Json que en este caso es ("item"), pero no sé como reconocer en la vista cual fue su rol para poder mostrarle los modulos correspondientes. Este fue mi intento y no me funciono.¿Que hago mal?

//Vista

```
   @{
                                    if (ViewBag("Rol") == "Admin")
                                    {
                                        <li class="kt-menu__section ">
                                            <h4 class="kt-menu__section-text">Sistema Gestion Energia</h4>
                                            <i class="kt-menu__section-icon flaticon-more-v2"></i>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="kt-menu__item  kt-menu__item--submenu" aria-haspopup="true" data-ktmenu-submenu-toggle="hover">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" class="kt-menu__link kt-menu__toggle"><i class="kt-menu__link-icon flaticon2-medical-records-1"></i><span class="kt-menu__link-text">SGE</span><i class="kt-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i></a>
                                            <div class="kt-menu__submenu ">
                                                <span class="kt-menu__arrow"></span>
                                                <ul class="kt-menu__subnav">
                                                    <li class="kt-menu__item  kt-menu__item--parent" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="kt-menu__link"><span class="kt-menu__link-text">Sistema Gestión de Energia</span></span></li>
                                                    <li class="kt-menu__item  kt-menu__item--submenu" aria-haspopup="true" data-ktmenu-submenu-toggle="hover">
                                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SistemaGE", new { Area = "SGE" })" class="kt-menu__link kt-menu__toggle"><i class="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--line"><span></span></i><span class="kt-menu__link-text">Report SGE</span><i class="kt-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i></a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="kt-menu__item  kt-menu__item--submenu" aria-haspopup="true" data-ktmenu-submenu-toggle="hover">
                                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Dispositivos", new { Area = "SGE" })" class="kt-menu__link kt-menu__toggle"><i class="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--line"><span></span></i><span class="kt-menu__link-text">Dispositivos </span><i class="kt-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i></a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }

                       




//Controlador

 public async Task<ActionResult> Iniciar([FromBody] LoginE login)
        {
            
             login.App = _app;
            ResponseE<UsuarioBasicoE> item = await _loginHelper.Autorizacion(login);

            ViewBag["Rol"] = item;
            
            
            return Json(item);
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

La solución a esto es tener 2 tablas en la base de datos, una donde agregas todos los items o menus que tengas y en otra tienes los items de los roles del usuario.
Entonces con alguna clave secundaria en la tabla de menus, pones a que rol pertenecen.

Con esto cuando consultes el usuario, consultas el rol de este,  y con esta información consultarías los menus que están asignados a ese rol, y esos valores serán los que tienes que presentar en tu vista.